# Regular expression for notepad++ to delete characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to create a regular expression in Notepad++ for a very long file. Many lines include some info I need to delete. For example a line would say:

> [THEME] An Openhouse [THEME] [THEME] how to make one [THEME] According to the number of people that...

And with the help of the regular expression my result should be just:

> According to the number of people that...

Comment: So you're trying to remove everything from the first `[THEME]` to the last `[THEME]`? Is that across the whole file or across every line? And have you tried anything so far?

Comment: you should detail your question better and add the code you attempted and what went wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

Did you try anything, like

```
 \[THEME\].*\[THEME\]
```

The `.*` is "greedy" so should try to span the longest stretch it can to make a match.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions have to be made since you weren't very clear on your requirements. The following three approaches will all create your result from your sample... but could have different affects if your sample changes slightly.

---

Assuming you want to remove everything except what exists after the last `[THEME]` if one exists for each line, this would work:

```
.*\[THEME\]
```

replaced with nothing.

---

Assuming you want to remove everything between the first and last `[THEME]` if they exist for each line, this would work:

```
\[THEME\].*\[THEME\]
```

replaced with nothing.

---

Assuming you want to remove anything between two `[THEME]`s could be more complicated, but a naive approach could look something like this:

```
\[THEME\].*?\[THEME\]
```

replaced with nothing. This would make:

> [THEME] An Openhouse [THEME] foobar [THEME] how to make one [THEME] According to the number of people that...

into this (pay attention to the "foobar"):

> foobar  According to the number of people that...